# Validate one method C#

Tags: c#, validation

If I have one validating method `Method1` which returns e.Cancel true or false, and which looks like this:

```
private void textBox1_Validating_1(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    ErrorProvider errorProvider = new ErrorProvider();

    bool isEmpty = String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text);
    if (isEmpty)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        errorProvider.SetError(textBox1, "txt");
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
        errorProvider.SetError(textBox1, "");
    }
}
```

And I want to get the result of validation, in my other method, here:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //bool passed = this.Validate(textBox1_Validating_1);
    if (passed == false) return;
```

I would want something like this:

```
bool passed = this.Validate(textBox1_Validating_1);
```

Only to validate this one method. How do I do it?

I am able to do it like this:

```
            bool passed = this.ValidateChildren();
        if (passed == false) return;
```

But if I do that, then I validate all my methods, but I one want to validate just this one `Method1`
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: not clear be explain more

Comment: What is the issue? What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public bool IsValidated()
    {
    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text);
    }
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        bool passed = IsValidated();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest to create a separate method for validation and call it on submit. Try this :

```
 private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ValidateControls()==0)
        {
           //Form is validated
        }
    }

int ValidateControls()
{
    int flag = 0;
    errorProvider1.Clear();
    if (txtAge.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtAge, "Age is required");
        flag = 1;
    }
    ............................................
    ............................................
   // validate all controls
    ............................................
    ............................................

    if (txtSalary.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtSalary, "Salary is required");
        flag = 1;
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var cnclEvent = new CancelEventArgs();

textBox1_Validating_1(null, cnclEvent);
if (cnclEvent.Cancel) return;
```